# When changing a proto field message type to `repeated`, what does "merge all input elements" mean?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Lets say I have a message

```
message Something {
  int32 foo = 1;
  int32 bar = 2;
  string baz = 3;
}
```

and another message

```
message SomethingElse {
  Something something = 1;
}
```

If I were to change this to repeated

```
message SomethingElse {
  repeated Something something = 1;
}
```

The doc https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#updating states that it will "merge all input elements" for the legacy clients that expect this to be optional.

What does "merge all input elements" mean?